# How to initialize VB.Net Logging from existing log4net configuration file?

Tags: vb.net, logging

I recently read that it is possible to define the `Log4Net` Config XML in defining this file in a class attribute.

```
<Assembly: log4net.Config.XMLConfigurator(ConfigFile:="Log4Net.Config.xml", Watch:=True)>
```

How can I define this file using only pure `VB.Net` code without using `Attribute` technique ?

Example (this is only textuals examples)

```
log4net.Config.OpenFile("Log4Net.Config.xml")
log4net.OpenConfigFile("Log4Net.Config.xml")
log4net.InitLoggingConfigFile("Log4Net.Config.xml")
```

The configuration's file already exists.
I search only the code that read it to configure logging.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Log4Net in a separate configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892021/log4net-in-a-separate-configuration-file)

Comment: The following may be of interest:  https://blog.elmah.io/log4net-tutorial-the-complete-guide-for-beginners-and-pros/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73759817/built-a-service-but-memory-keeps-climbing/73806343#73806343

Answer (score 1):

To solve your issue, you can use XmlConfigurator.Configure() function

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo(args[0]));
```

that is explained on [Apache Net4Net site](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html)